# Recovering a logical volume who's disk has been removed and plugged back in?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, lvm, lvm2

The reasoning behind what I've done is a long story, so I won't delve into details, but here's where I'm at:

Take a HDD in a USB->SATA box, and plug it in to a machine, comes up as /dev/sde(1)

```
lvcreate /dev/dataVG/data /dev/sde1 
mount /dev/dataVG/data /mnt
cp data/mystuff /mnt
umount /mnt
```

unplug the USB->SATA drive and plug the drive directly in as SATA. I moved some other drives around in the process, and after a reboot, this drive is now /dev/sdc(1).

`lvdisplay` no longer shows the volume group, and mount shows the standard "corrupt fs, missing helper page" message.

The data on this drive is quite important, and it's there because the original has physically failed and will be difficult to recover (more for business/political reasons than anything else, I'm not afraid of a soldering iron but the rest of the company is). So I'm looking to do this as carefully and elegantly as possible so as not to lose the data.

How can I reconstruct the logical volume given that it was made of only one physical volume, the data is (in theory) still all there, all that's changed is that it's moved locations in /dev?

Edit: fdisk -l says that the original and new sector size match, but the partition size is all wrong (this is a 5.5T drive, with 2.5T of data on it, but the whole thing is partitioned)

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes            
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos                                         
Disk identifier: 0x09573ba3          
                                                 
Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         256 1465130645 1465130390 698.6G 83 Linux
```

Update - losetup seems to be showing me the partition, but since it's an lvm2 member I can't mount it directly, so now it's on to resurrecting the logical volume that's on there. I'm seeing:

```
mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

So I need to re-make the lvm disk, I imagine lvcreate is not the right method to do this, but I'm not sure what is.

Comment: First test - put it back in the box. Some external drive adapters put 'fake' sector size data in the hardware [it works for compatibility, but fails if you remove that hardware translation.]

Comment: ^^^True. Compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511256/108618)

Comment: I'll have to give that a go, that makes sense. Unfortunately I don't have physical access at the moment, so if I can avoid going to the office (I'm WFH) by fixing this remotely, that would be ideal.

Comment: The hypothesis stands. The numbers `256`, `1465130645`, `1465130390` were valid for logical sector size of `4096`. Partition table of the type `dos` cannot be easily corrected; besides you may want not to change the partition table permanently. What you can do ad-hoc is to use `losetup` to "extract" the *right* fragment of the disk as a block device. Please confirm your `losetup` supports `-o` and `--sizelimit` (see `man 8 losetup`). Does it support `--sector-size`? After `losetup` creates a device for you, you will use it *instead of* `/dev/sdc1` with other tools (like `lvcreate`, I guess).

Comment: I understand now - I was looking at the logical/physical matching, not the sectors in the partition vs real sectors

Comment: I think the command will be like `sudo losetup -f --show -o "$((4096*256))" --sizelimit "$((4096*1465130390))" --sector-size 4096 --read-only /dev/sdc`, where `--read-only` is just in case. The newly created device should behave like `/dev/sde1` used to (with USB->SATA). In the end you destroy the device with `sudo losetup -d …`. Please give feedback if this is useful.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that, just gotta work the politics out simultaneously. Will losetup create an entry in /dev?
Also - when I detach with -d, does that leave me screwed (is this a one time thing?)

Comment: Probably in `/dev/mapper/`.